# How do I open external links in different profiles with Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I have two instances of firefox running under separate profiles:

```
$ firefox -P default &
...
$ firefox -no-remote -P second &
```

Now I can open a new tab from the command line with:

```
$ firefox -new-tab http://unix.stackexchange.com
```

But how do I open a new tab in the second profile?

This:

```
$ firefox -P second -new-tab http://unix.stackexchange.com
```

opens a tab in the default profile, while:

```
$ firefox -no-remote -P second -new-tab http://unix.stackexchange.com
```

complains that there is already an instance running under that profile.

Comment: You need to use `-new-instance` instead of `-no-remote` (see [bug #716110](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=716110)). But even that doesn't work as of Firefox 29: `firefox -P second URL` still contacts the first instance.

Comment: *Gilles*s comment above has ceased to be true as of `firefox  39` see comments below.

Answer (score 3):

It works now with `firefox` 29.0 on Linux:

To open a second `firefox` instance with a different profile:

`firefox -P second -new-instance`

To open a new tab in the second instance of `firefox`, which os already running:

`firefox -P second -remote "openurl(http://example.com,new-tab)"`

See [Bug 716110 - split -new-instance flag out of existing -no-remote flag](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=716110) for additional hints (eg: post of Hayo).

As explained in the comments on this bug report, what is missing is a command that can be used for opening the first window and the second tab in the same way:

That could be done with a script along the lines of this (`firefox-profile-instance`):

```
#!/bin/bash

PROFILE="$1"
URL="$2"

if firefox -P "$PROFILE" -remote "ping()" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    firefox -P "$PROFILE" -remote "openurl($URL,new-tab)"
else
    firefox -P "$PROFILE" -new-instance "$URL" &
fi
```

Now, while a firefox with the default profile is already running,
the first run of this starts a new browser with profile "second":

`firefox-profile-instance second "http://example.com"`

and running the same again opens a second tab in the same browser:

`firefox-profile-instance second "http://example.com"`

Comment: The `-remote` option has been [removed from firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#Remote_Control). However, the existing commands `-new-window`, `-new-tab` and the generic open command have been extended to support the -P argument (true in firefox 52)..

Comment: There appears to be no equivalent to the `-remote ping()` option. This can be replaced with a call to `pgrep` (see answer below).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is very much an extension of *Volker Siegel*'s answer above and I'm happy for the two to be merged. I am only writing this to format a new script given that firefox no longer supports `-remote`.

New versions of Firefox (tested with version 52) support a `-new-instance` option for spawning a new instance that supports remote calls. Subsequent calls to firefox, if given a `-P` argument, will carry out actions in a running firefox profile with the given profile name.

If you wish to combine spawning and link opening into one script then this can be achieved using `pgrep` as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash
profile=profile-name
if pgrep --full "^firefox-esr\b.*$profile" > /dev/null; then
    firejail --profile=$HOME/.firejail/firefox.jail.profile firefox -P "$profile" "$@" > /dev/null
else
    firejail --profile=$HOME/.firejail/firefox.jail.profile firefox -new-instance -P "$profile" "$@"
    disown $!
fi
```

(Warning this script has not been tested, but is adapted from one that I use)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from [@Att Righ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128616/how-do-i-open-external-links-in-different-profiles-with-firefox/407152#407152) I developed the following solution which automatically selects the right profile based on the URL.

This wrapper script is tested on Ubuntu Linux 20.04.6 with Mozilla Firefox 104.0.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$@" =~ .*"google."|"facebook.com"|"instagram.com".* ]] 
then
    profile=for_evil_sites
else
    profile=default
fi  

if pgrep --full "firefox\b.*$profile" > /dev/null; then
    /usr/bin/firefox -P "$profile" "$@" > /dev/null
else
    /usr/bin/firefox --new-instance -P "$profile" "$@" > /dev/null
    disown $!
fi
```

Save the script with the name `firefox` e.g. in `$HOME/bin/` and make sure it will be loaded instead of your standard firefox. (The directory has to be before the original one in variable `$PATH`.)